# Accented Character showing as Ã© in a pdf Using Persits.PDF

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, pdf, fonts, pdf-generation

I'm trying to display a name on a pdf using Persits.PDF [(Persits URL)](http://www.asppdf.net/), this particular name has a an accented character in it, this being `é`

When I use the Arial font it works fine:

```
Dim standardFont As PdfFont = doc.Fonts.Item("Arial")
```

However when I use Helvetica, `é` is shown as `Ã©`

```
Dim standardFont As PdfFont = doc.Fonts.Item("Helvetica")

strParams = "x=" & (leftMarginX + CDbl(1345)).ToString() & "; y=660; width=1430.5; size=42; color=#000000;"
page.Canvas.DrawText(strFullName, strParams, standardFont)
```

In above code `page = Persits.PDF.PdfPage` and `doc = Persits.PDF.PdfDocument`

How can I get Helvetica to display this character?

Comment: It seems this tools has a bug with some fonts. Anyway, could you try this: `page.Canvas.DrawText(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(strFullName))`, etc.

Comment: @SimonMourier When I try this I get a Character out of Range error from the control.

Comment: which control? It may mean this character is not supported for this font

Comment: The PDF control I'm using. The font is working for standard charaters, it's been in use for years. I think you may be right about it being a bug.

Comment: Looks like a UTF-8 problem. Did you verify that you have no switch between encodings throughout your app and it's libraries?

Comment: @ToBe Normally I would agree, however this works fine with Arial font

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i think the documentation tells you that it's not supported in Helvetica - see [support.persits.com](http://support.persits.com/show.asp?code=PS040206127)

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. However, I can use this line with any font. `Doc.Fonts.LoadFromFile("c:\winnt\fonts\arial.ttf")`. The points are yours, thanks.