# Characters not displaying correctly on a UTF-8 website

Tags: php, mysql, html, utf-8, html-entities

I've done everything I can think of, but special characters are not displaying correctly on this webpage.

For example, in the database it's:

[image]

But on the site it's:

```
Nouveaux R�alistes
```

Here's everything I've checked...

The database is set to UTF-8:

[image]

The page was written in NetBeans, with the document encoding set to UTF-8:

[image]

The page header declares UTF-8:

[image]

The meta charset is set to UTF-8:

[image]

I've even added the following line to my .htacess:

[image]

But there characters are still not displaying correctly, and I get the following error from the W3C Validator:

[image]

I feel like I've attempted everything, but it still won't work. (I've even tried `htmlspecialchars` and `htmlentities` in PHP, but the page doesn't even render!)

---

**UPDATE**
As requested, here is the code I'm using:

```
class Exhibition {
    public $exhibitionDetails;    

    public function __construct(Database $db, $exhibitionID){
        $this->_db = $db;

        $params['ExhibitionID'] = $exhibitionID;

        $STH = $this->_db->prepare("SELECT * 
            FROM Exhibition
            INNER JOIN Schedule
                ON Exhibition.ExhibitionID = Schedule.ExhibitionID            
            WHERE Schedule.Visible = 1
                AND Exhibition.ExhibitionID = :ExhibitionID;");

        $STH->execute($params);

        $this->exhibitionDetails = $STH->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    }
}
```

And...

```
try {
    $db = new Database(SITE_ROOT."/../");
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $exhibition = new Exhibition($db,$_GET['id']);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "<p class='error'>ERROR: ".$e->getMessage()."</p>";
}
```

And finally...

```
<p><?php echo $exhibition->exhibitionDetails[0]["Desc"]; ?></p>
```

Comment: I guess you just encoding too much. Can you show your php code which fetches the records and output it?

Comment: What font are you using? I had a similar issue with a pdf. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15787001/accented-character-showing-as-in-a-pdf-using-persits-pdf)

Comment: It seems that your data in the database is not encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: @Gumbo I've pasted the data into a UTF-8 encoded document in NetBeans. Saved it, closed it, reopened it, and checked the text. It looked good, so I cut and pasted it back into the database... but still the same result. Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: How do you insert the data into the database?

Comment: @Gumbo It was my database connection encoding, exactly as IAmNotProcrastinating predicted. Hurrah!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using `mysql_*` functions:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

If you are using `PDO`

```
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';
$options = array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',
); 

$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
```

It sets connection encoding.

Comment: I can't quite see how I'd work this into my code. I'm hopeful that you're right, though!

Comment: Look inside `Database` class for `new PDO`.

Comment: At least [with the *mysql* API, you shouldn’t use `SET NAMES` but `mysql_set_charset`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5289141/53114) instead.

Comment: Thanks for share it @Gumbo, i think it will be usefull in a non-distant future :)

Comment: It can cause problems, the `mysql_*` functions don't react to direct SET NAMES, that's why you must go through `mysql_set_charset`. No reason not to use it since it's even easier to write and read.

Comment: @Gumbo Could you perhaps explain how to implement your solution?

Comment: That way: `mysql_set_charset('utf8',$conn)`, perhaps, it's not your case, @DjangoReinhardt. Your connection is PDO-based, and not mysql_*-based.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a few years since I've used PHP but back then it didn't natively support Unicode and  a quick search of google tells me it still doesn't. You can still make it work though.

Here's a great link:

[Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)