# Ukrainian word (схожі) not working in url

Tags: php, url, utf-8, multilingual

I have a question related to multi language website..

- Added `AddDefaultCharset utf-8` in .htaccess
- Added this line `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` in every page
- All pages changes to `Unicode-UTF-8` from `Western European` using dreamweaver page properties
- Database collation - `utf8_general_ci`

Russian, Japanese, Ukrainian, Chinese, Korean most of these languages and words are working properly except these word **схожі-ігри**

This word is ukrainian language - **схожі-ігри** . It stored into db table successfully and it also fetches the word properly. But, It doesn't work in url. When I go to this link **www.mydomain.com/uk/схожі-ігри/** it says object not found.

But other href link ukrainian words are working properly except this one. Then I removed **x** from this word

**сожі-ігри** instead of **схожі-ігри**

This word **сожі-ігри** is working fine in url. But this is a wrong word. Last 3 hours I try to find the solution. I don't have any idea.

Comment: have you tried to put the url manualy or you take it just from db?

Comment: I know the problem, I had similar.. let me just find in one of my projects and I will post it for you, maybe it will also solve your problem...

Comment: @vsambor : ok. I will wait

Comment: are u using a framework ? how do you handle the incoming requests? do you have a custom router implemented?

Comment: @Andreas : no framework

Comment: OK no framework but r u using a custom router? If you do use a router can u debug the request URI when the client requests www.mydomain.com/uk/схожі-ігри/ ?

Answer (score 0):

I used this :

```
function getDB() {
    global $dataBase;
    if($dataBase == null) {
        $dataBase = new DataBase();
    }
    $db = $dataBase->getConnection();


    //This are important things to query before you make any request from db...
    $db->query('set character_set_client=utf8');
    $db->query('set character_set_connection=utf8');
    $db->query('set character_set_results=utf8');
    $db->query('set character_set_server=utf8');
    return  $db;
}
```

Try it and tell me if it works...

Comment: try to change connection query to 'utf8_general_ci'

Comment: try to look also at <b>utf8mb4</b>  link here: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4

Comment: have you tried setlocale(LC_ALL, 'fr_CA.utf-8'); or look here maybe you'll find something interesting about SET NAMES http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16092448/characters-not-displaying-correctly-on-a-utf-8-website